# react local storage doesnt work , ı dont why ,

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

> ı am set items to local storage , and getting from local storage,
> when set item to local storage it work, but when ı refresh page all
> ıtem ın the local storage it disappearing.

```
  //* local storage get notes
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    const localNotes=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('react-note-app-data'));
    if(localNotes){

      setNoteData(localNotes)
    }
  },[])

  //* local storage set notes
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    localStorage.setItem('react-note-app-data',JSON.stringify(noteData))
  },[noteData])
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are setting in local storage, give a check whether noteData is there or not. Because useEffect always run after render and then next it will run when any of its dependency get change, Try below code might it fix the issue for you

```
 //* local storage get notes
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    const localNotes=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('react-note-app-data'));
    if(localNotes){

      setNoteData(localNotes)
    }
  },[])

  //* local storage set notes
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    if (noteData) { // added if check, to check wether noteData variable has value if yes then set the value in localStorage else not.
        localStorage.setItem('react-note-app-data',JSON.stringify(noteData))
    }
    
  },[noteData])
```

Comment: still doesnt work, why?

Comment: Does Localstorage get empty after adding if condition?

Comment: when add note it save local storage , but when ı reffresh its diseppear, maybe

Comment: how to share my code